# Get clients only if they are born in 09 month

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a problem with a message " invalid relational operator"

```
select distinct ig.describe from info_groupe ig 
inner join client_info ki on (ig.id=ki.id_info_group) 
where exists (select * from client k inner join client_contact kk
on (k.id=kk.id_client)  where kk.location='B'
 and kk.type_contact= 'EMAIL'
 AND substr(date, 4, 2),
 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'MM' ='09' 
 order by describe desc;
```

Except month, i have to satisfy condition that the `location ="B"` and `type_contact = "EMAIL"`. 
What I want is to display "`describe`" with the condition location is B and type contact = Email for all clients that have date (for example 01.09.88) month 09

Comment: How is your date stored? if it is a `date`, you get the month with only `extract(month from date_field)` or `to_char(date, 'MM')`; if it is a `varchar2` ( and it is not a good idea), it depends on how it is stored; assuming the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, you get the month with only `substr(date_field, 3, 2)`

Comment: @Aleksej , it's date. Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT( MONTH FROM <date column> )`:

```
select distinct ig.describe
from   info_groupe ig 
       inner join client_info ki
       on (ig.id=ki.id_info_group) 
where exists ( select *
               from   client k
                      inner join client_contact kk
                      on (k.id=kk.id_client)
               where  kk.location='B'
               and    kk.type_contact= 'EMAIL'
               AND    EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date ) = 9
             ) 
order by describe desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct ig.describe from info_groupe ig 
inner join client_info ki on (ig.id=ki.id_info_group) 
where exists (select * from client k inner join client_contact kk
               on (k.id=kk.id_client)  where kk.location='B'
                 and kk.type_contact= 'EMAIL'
                 AND to_char(date,'MM') ='09' 
                 AND ki.id = kk.id_client)
order by describe desc
```

I assumed that you have column of client id in client_info, i called it id_client, if its different then change it.

I used to_char(date,'MM') to get the month.

Comment: yes in the table client_info exists column "id" and "id" is joined with "id_client" in client_contact kk  (  ... WHERE ki.id = kk.id_client)) . But i get "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: I just removed "  AND ki.id = kk.id_client) ", and now works, return all 9 rows